Splunk query to find those final results that has events with unique combination of values of two keys in results of main search criteria
I have a Splunk query like this:
index=my_app environment=test source="/users/sahild/app.log" "fname" OR "lname" OR "dob" OR "address" | <>
Now, from the initial results of the main query (before pipeline), I need to filter out the results/events so that for a unique combination of "cls" and "mthd" duplicate results are removed. For example, if my initial results are:
2024-08-28 23:07:30,285 INFO  {"msg":"Response: {\"Output\":[{\"Address\":\"Bay Rd\",\"PostalCode\":\"12345\","cls":"myfirstclass","mthd":"firstMethod"}

2024-08-28 23:07:30,285 INFO  {"msg":"Response: {\"Output\":[{\"Address\":\"Lincoln Rd\",\"PostalCode\":\"45678\","cls":"myfirstclass","mthd":"firstMethod"}

2024-08-28 23:07:30,285 INFO  {"msg":"Response: {\"Output\":[{\"fName\":\"John\",\"PostalCode\":\"12345\","cls":"mySecondClass","mthd":"secondMethod"}

2024-08-28 23:07:30,285 INFO  {"msg":"Response: {\"Output\":[{\"fName\":\"Emma\",\"PostalCode\":\"45678\","cls":"mySecondClass","mthd":"secondMethod"}

I want to filter out the results/events such that I get records that has a unique combined value of "cls" and "mthd", appearing only once. so final result should look something like:
2024-08-28 23:07:30,285 INFO  {"msg":"Response: {\"Output\":[{\"Address\":\"Lincoln Rd\",\"PostalCode\":\"45678\","cls":"myfirstclass","mthd":"firstMethod"}

2024-08-28 23:07:30,285 INFO  {"msg":"Response: {\"Output\":[{\"fName\":\"John\",\"PostalCode\":\"12345\","cls":"mySecondClass","mthd":"secondMethod"}

Because for the initial search I am getting hundreds of thousands of results but I don't want the repeating data for same cls and mthd. I hope my ask is clear.
I could not try much for the query after the pipeline since I don't have much knowledge of splunk regex or functions that can be used to achieve this. Need some expert help.

Are your events really like that? It seems like JSON data with escaped JSON data but it isn't valid and is broken. Is it all seen as plain text in Splunk or are the JSON properties queryable? Meaning, do you need to extract cls and mthd or are they already Splunk fields you could query on?

They are not Splunk query fields directly. Those are needed to be extracted as Splunk fields before I can use any operation on that. And the event data is just _raw type, it is not a JSON directly. The example JSON might be invaid because of typo but "msg" is just a sibling JSON element to "cls" and "mthd".

I found a solution. I need to use rex commands to pull out "cls" and "mthd" as Splunk fields so that I can use Splunk operations on those. Something like this:
index=myIndex environment=test source="/path/to/logsfile/demo.log" ("firstName" OR "lastName") AND "mthd" AND "cls" 
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "(?<ClassAndMethodName>\"cls\"\:\"\w*\",\"mthd\"\:\"\w*\")" 
| dedup ClassAndMethodName

This query gives me only those events which have unique combined value of cls and mthd.

You can use stats and first()
| stats first(_raw) as "raw" by cls mthd
| fields raw

If cls and mthd aren't already available fields (it's unclear if those are supposed to be escaped JSON properties in the Response property or are siblings to the msg. It seems your JSON is invalid, but unclear if that's really like that on your system or was typeo in your examples.
You might need to extract those fields before grouping with stats.
